# Query admins from a usergroups table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create an edit page for a Group of Users that only admins can see.
I created 3 models:

group.rb:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
...
  has_many :user_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups
...
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
...
  has_many :user_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups
...
end
```

usergroups.rb:

```
class UserGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  validates_presence_of :user_id
  validates_presence_of :group_id
end
```

The usergroups model is the one that includes a boolean field, 'true' when the user is an admin. Here the schema.rb for the mentioned models:

```
  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.integer "type"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_groups_on_slug", unique: true
    t.index ["type"], name: "index_groups_on_type"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_groups_on_user_id"
  end

    create_table "user_groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "group_id"
    t.boolean "is_admin"
    t.boolean "is_owner"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_user_groups_on_group_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_user_groups_on_user_id"
  end

    create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "username", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end
```

My question is:

**How do I scope the admins using the "is_admin" field in usergroups.rb?**
I've been trying with something like "group.usergroups.is_admin?" but no results with this.

For clearing doubts, the authorization will be done by 'pundit', what I do not have clear is how to scope the admins. I'm using rails 5.2 and ruby 2.6.

Any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: It is probably just me, but I do not understand what scope you need exactly. Do you want to get a list of groups a given user can edit because he is admin of? Or do you want to get all admins of a given group? What exactly is the use case? A pundit scope for an index page of groups? Or the policy if a user is allowed to update a group?

Comment: Hi @spickermann. I need a list of admins of a given group, but I not clear about creating a scope or something else... The pundit policy should give editing access to admins only. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with something like this:

```
class GroupPolicy
  def update?
    UserGroup.where(user_id: user.id, group_id: group.id, is_admin: true).exists?
  end
end
```

Which can be used in the controller's update method like

```
authorize @group
```

or in a view – for example, to show edit links – like this

```
<% if policy(@group).update? %>
  <%= link_to "Edit group", edit_group_path(@group) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Small refactor `UserGroup.exists?(user_id: user.id, group_id: group.id, is_admin: true)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help or lead to a better solution for you.

Once you have an instance of `Group`, let's say `@group`, you can query [joining the tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables):

```
admins = @group.user_groups.joins(:user).where("user_groups.is_admin = true")
```

Then you should be able to do something like:

```
admins.each { |admin| p admin.user.name }
```

---

You could define in your model:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups

  def admins
    user_groups.joins(:user).where("user_groups.is_admin = true")
  end
end
```

In order to call just `@group.admins`

---

Another option in pure Ruby, given the @group is:

```
admins = group.user_groups.select { |ug| ug.is_admin }
```

Comment: finally I opted for pundit solution, although the two answers solved my doubt. I would like to be able to mark 2 as correct. Thanks!!